# Mouse-over Navigation for jCoverflip

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jCoverflip, and would like it to turn when I move the mouse to either side.... I can't find anything on how to do this... I'm using the basic setup:

```
$('.items').jcoverflip();
<ul class="items">
  <li class="item"><a href="#"><img src=""><span class="title">My title 1</span></a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#"><img src=""><span class="title">My title 2</span></a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#"><img src=""><span class="title">My title 3</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that, you want to move / slide your image on mouseover rather than click. The you have to change the configuration ie jCoverflip.js file.

You should be able to change line 542 of jquery.jcoverflip.js from:

```
this.element.click( proxy( this, this._clickItem ) );
```

to

```
this.element.mouseover( proxy( this, this._clickItem ) );
```

I hope this will work for you.